# C#- How to handle string terminator in the conversion

Tags: c#, string

I have a binary array. In the process of conversion it into string,due to some data my string gets terminated. and it ignores next data.Have a look on my code. Is there is any mistake??

```
str += (char)chunkData[index].ToString();
```

Later on i want to display it on textbox.
My array contains following data as display in hex editor.

````
 xÚb```e``*bxÚb`
    ¨€ˆY8ÄX¡˜A‰“yuZs˜#µjÑ‚Ð¬i@š
    È4„è0
````

**I tried this but nothing change..
str = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(chunkData);**

Comment: Does .NET has the same \0 as string terminating character? A little confused over what character could be causing this?

Comment: Well, then I guess that your text contains \0 - this terminates the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use text to represent arbitrary binary data. You will almost *certainly* lose data if you just use Encoding.GetString and Encoding.GetBytes.

If you really want to convert arbitrary binary data to text and back, use [`Convert.ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx) and [`Convert.FromBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx).

As for '\0' termination: .NET strings themselves don't rely on termination characters, but many UI controls (including `TextBox`) *will* treat '\0' as a termination character.

Comment: About \0 termination: Really? I didn't know that - how is the length of a .NET string being determined?

Comment: +1 for Convert.ToBase64String. I think thats the correct way to show arbitrary data in TextBox or any control. User will be unable to interpret it anyway. Regarding the termination char, I would like to text the '\0' thing with a textbox.

Comment: @Thorsten: The string object has the length as a separate variable.

Answer (score 2):

See [Encoding.GetString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc.aspx) with the encoding matching your binary data.

```
str = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(chunkData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your "mistake" is *not using* the `Encoding.GetString(byte[])` call for that :-)